# Twilio Programmable Video: when dominantSpeaker changes, the audio seems to increase in volume and build static

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I have implemented an interface in such a way that `dominantSpeaker` is enabled for displaying their picture in the main window, but all participants can always be heard.  To achieve this, I had to comment out the `audioTrack.detach()` in `useEffect()`  The issue that I'm having is that each time the `dominantSpeaker` changes, it seems to amplify their volume and begin producing static.  It gets progressively worse until its inaudible, at which point when I reload the page the audio is fixed for me.  Every participant is having the same problem, and the issue is only resolved for the individual that refreshes the page.  Even when all of the users are muted, the static persists.  When I go into the console and delete all of the  and  tags, the static still persists.

I am passing a prop to the Participant Component which is true if it is the `dominant_window`.  I do this because I wanted the audio of each individual speaker to come from their small participant window, thus allowing multiple audio streams at once.  When I comment out the Participant which is the dominant_window, I get no sound even though it doesn't render an  tag at all in the first place.

I've tried rendering it without the `<audio>` and `<video>` components and I still get audio.  This leads me to think that the audio is not coming from the audio tag I'm setting at all.  My assumption is that because I've commented out the `audioTrack.detach()` that it's adding the same audioTrack over and over to whatever is controlling the audio, thus increasing the volume (although this doesn't explain the static when everyone is muted), but when it's there I can only get 1 participant audio at a time.

Where exactly is the audio coming from?  How do I monitor whatever/where ever that is?  How do I ensure the audioTrack is only added once per person if it is a solitary item controlling all audio and allow everyone to speak at once using `dominantSpeaker`?

Participant.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

const Participant = ({  key,
                         dominant_window,
                         user,
                         participant,
                         width,
                         videoEnabled,
                         audioEnabled,
                         onMouseEnter,
                         onMouseLeave,
                         is_fullscreen,
                         tiled,
                     }) => {
    const [videoTracks, setVideoTracks] = useState([]);
    const [audioTracks, setAudioTracks] = useState([]);
    const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);

    const videoRef = useRef();
    const audioRef = useRef();

    const trackpubsToTracks = trackMap => {
        const tracks = Array.from(trackMap.values()).map(publication => publication.track);
        return tracks;
    };

    const handleTrackChange =
        useEffect(() => {
            const trackSubscribed = track => {
                if (track.kind === 'video') {
                    setVideoTracks(videoTracks => [...videoTracks, track]);
                } else {
                    setAudioTracks(audioTracks => [...audioTracks, track]);
                }
            };

            const trackUnsubscribed = track => {
                if (track.kind === 'video') {
                    setVideoTracks(videoTracks => videoTracks.filter(v => v !== track));
                } else {
                    setAudioTracks(audioTracks => audioTracks.filter(a => a !== track));
                }
            };
            setVideoTracks(trackpubsToTracks(participant.videoTracks));
            setAudioTracks(trackpubsToTracks(participant.audioTracks));

            participant.on('trackSubscribed', trackSubscribed);
            participant.on('trackUnsubscribed', trackUnsubscribed);

            return () => {
                setVideoTracks([]);
                setAudioTracks([]);
            };
        }, [participant]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const videoTrack = videoTracks[0];
        if (videoTrack) {
            videoTrack.attach(videoRef.current);
            return () => {
                //videoTrack.detach();
            };
        }
    }, [videoTracks]);


    useEffect(() => {
        const audioTrack = audioTracks[0];

        if (audioTrack) {
            audioTrack.attach(audioRef.current);
            return () => {
                //audioTrack.detach();
            };
        }
    }, [audioTracks]);
    
    return (
        <div key={key}
             onMouseEnter={() => {
                 if (onMouseEnter) onMouseEnter();
                 setHovered(true)
             }}
             onMouseLeave={() => {
                 if (onMouseLeave) onMouseLeave();
                 setHovered(false)
             }}
        >

            <video className='participant-video'
                    ref={videoRef}
                    autoPlay={true}
                    style={{
                        transform: participant.identity == `u_${user.id}` ? "scaleX(-1)" : "scaleX(1)",
                        opacity: videoEnabled ? "1" : "0",
                        zIndex: videoEnabled ? "1" : "-1"
                    }}/>
            {(audioEnabled && !dominant_window && !(participant.identity == `u_${user.id}`)) && <audio ref={audioRef} autoPlay={true} muted={false}/>}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Participant;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was reattaching the track each time the dominantSpeaker changed, duplicating it.  The increase in volume and static was due to it playing the same track on top of itself.